# HTML5 / JS Constraint validation Bug

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate a form using the Constraint Validation API to customize error messages.

According to mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)
everything should work, but I have a strange bug when I try to validate a simple mail input, invalid mail is not detected.

Here a sample of my code :

```
<input type="mail" id="mail" name="mail"/>
```

then the object is stored in JS, and I check in console with :

```
console.log(field.get(0).validity);
```

The answer from the console is :

```
customError : false
patternMismatch : false
rangeOverflow : false
rangeUnderflow : false  
stepMismatch : false    
tooLong : false 
typeMismatch : false
valid : false   
valueMissing : true
```

So I assume the function call is working.

If I leave the input empty, same answer. If I put "a" or random string, same answer.
If I put a valid mail, same answer...

If I put a required attribute, emptyness is detected...

Do you know what's happening ?

Is the API too young to be used, or I missed something ?

What can I use as alternative ?

Thanks for reading, and sorry for my english.

Comment: It would be quite useful to specify which browser you're using.

Comment: It was firefox, but same on all browsers. Because PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using type `email`.

Have a look at the link you've posted.

Example:

```
<form>
  <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me an e-mail</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Type `mail` will be unrecognised. Simple as that.

Comment: O_o ... sure... Thanks a lot.
I lost 3hours of work for a "e". SHIT.